# Where can I get the correct and precise algorithms for elliptic curve cryptography?

Tags: elliptic-curves, reference-request, standards

I have been asked to implement cryptographic operations using elliptic curves. I would like to get precise algorithms for various processes like key generation, digital signature and verification. I found [this link](http://www.johannes-bauer.com/compsci/ecc/), but I just want confirmation on the algorithms provided there are correct or not. I would also like to know if there is any standard site for this topic whose information are authentic and can be trusted.

Comment: Wikipedia! It's a very reliable source. :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Standards for Efficient Cryptography Group](http://www.secg.org/) has published [SEC1: Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf) (pdf) about elliptic curve algorithms. If it does not explain the mathematics well enough for your purposes, there is also [Fundamental Elliptic Curve Cryptography Algorithms](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6090.txt) (RFC 6090, from IETF) you could look at.

There are a lot of issues you can run into, so hopefully this is an exercise of some kind, rather than someone expecting you to write production code from scratch. For production code I would recommend using existing libraries.

Comment: U mean open SSL libraries? and moreover I already have libraries for RSA based cryptographic operations. I just need to implement it using elliptic cures. Given this situation...would u still advice me to use existing libraries for ECC?

Comment: @abejoe, OpenSSL or one of the other alternatives, depends e.g. on what is feasible to integrate due to licensing. I would pretty much always advice against writing your own crypto code. Whenever possible, reuse something even moderately well vetted instead.

Comment: @abejoe Implementing symmetric crypto is usually not that dangerous, because most mistakes lead to it not working at all (you still need to be careful about side channel attacks). ECC is subtle, you need to correctly handle various special cases, failure to do so can lead to a rarely occurring yet exploitable bugs. So I *strongly* recommend not implementing ECC for production use yourself.